# How can I go forward in a file? What is the oposite of ctrl+O

Tags: vim, vi

If I jump to a file e.g. by `gf` I know that I can do `ctrl+O` to go back.
But how do I go forward? I.e. what is the opposite of `ctrl+O` so as to go forward to the file I was earlier to which I jumbed to via `gf`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The opposite of `<C-O>` is `<C-I>` a.k.a. `<Tab>`:

> CTRL-O            Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list
>
> Tab       or
>   CTRL-I            Go to [count] newer cursor position in jump list

`:jumps` will print the jump list, which is nice for orientation.

---

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: How would I use `:help` to find this topic for instance?

Comment: `:help CTRL-O`; you just need to know the command's mode and the spelling of keys!